# A better word than desire in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> My *desire* to heal, educate, and advocate for patients coupled with my hunger for knowledge align with the qualities of a physician, ultimately cementing this career choice as the perfect match for me.

A better word than "desire" in this context?

Comment: Objective......................any thesaurus will give you help with this.

Comment: Yes, please clarify what you mean by "better" - why do you think "desire" is a poor choice of words in this context? It looks fine to me (right up to "coupled with" where you seem to be running into grammatical issues...).

Comment: I am trying to show more passion and like a more intense feeling, and I feel like desire is too weak of a word.

Comment: @PShah "Desire" is actually quite a strong word here. The fact that it's been debased by overuse in silly pop songs is regrettable, but a "desire" is a deep and powerful want. Anything more powerful than a desire is an obsession, and you really don't want to use that here.